# Why is this timestring not recognised by momentjs-node?

Tags: node.js, time, momentjs

According to http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/ 20130208T080910 is a supported ISO 8601 string of moment.js. Node-red-contrib-moment is the Node-red implentation of this moment.js.

I'm sending "20170630T141515" to the moment node (Date/Time Formatter) and get the debug message "The input property was NOT a recognisable date. Output will be a blank string". What is my fault here, what can I do to get a nicely foramted date output string?

Comment: Have you tried sending "20170630T141515Z"?

Comment: Yes, this doesn't change anything :-/

Comment: I was able to duplicate your problem.  I also hit a problem where "TypeError: node.inTz.split is not a function" before the payload config is updated (you have to do something to save the editor at least once).  I'd suggest opening an issue on github; I don't know that I can dig any deeper (but I'll do what I can this week).

Answer (score 0):

In your case try to set the Moment parsing format to: **`YYYYMMDDTHHmmss`**

Vanilla JS with Moment.JS: **`moment("20170630T141515", "YYYYMMDDTHHmmss");`**